# antd custom primary color

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, create-react-app, antd

I am using antd and create-react-app to create my application.

I following this examplle:https://github.com/ant-design/antd-init/tree/master/examples/customize-antd-theme

> Here they have given example using webconfig. When i tried to replacete the same i m unable to change the primary color. Can anybody tell how to do the same in create-react-app ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**: People, please read the date of the answer. **It's from 2018**, It was the accepted answer at that time. Now probably it's outdated, please refer to the newest official documentation or answers.

#### 1st way Manually ejecting create-react-app

You need to eject with `npm run eject` to have control the webpack.config.js

then you can use LESS's modifyvars to change the primary color

just as the guide explains

here is an english version:

https://ant.design/docs/react/customize-theme

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader#less-options

#### 2nd. use react-app-rewire-less

Import it and modify config-overrides.js like below.

```
$ yarn add react-app-rewire-less --dev
  const { injectBabelPlugin } = require('react-app-rewired');
+ const rewireLess = require('react-app-rewire-less');

  module.exports = function override(config, env) {
-   config = injectBabelPlugin(['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: 'css' }], config);
+   config = injectBabelPlugin(['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }], config);  // change importing css to less
+   config = rewireLess.withLoaderOptions({
+     modifyVars: { "@primary-color": "#1DA57A" },
+   })(config, env);
    return config;
  };
```

Check more information here: https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

Comment: Thanks  @Kossel, it's very useful, currently I am very busy with other work and will try to run this at weekend

Comment: It's weird approach. Ant have embedded ways to customize colors without ejecting

Comment: @IgorPopov did you realized the question was answered in 2018? Many things have changed and that was the way to do it.

Comment: @Yichz yes. And implementation this without ejecting was in that year. And this answer google still give you in list of answer. Ejecting - not an answer ever.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use react-scripts eject
you can simply create a less file (let's say main.less ) , import antd.less and replace the default variables of ant design in this main.less file.

compile this less file using lessc (npm i -g less).

lessc "main.less antd.css" --js
--js is for inline javascript in less Now simply include these complied css in your app.

check out https://medium.com/@aksteps/782c53cbc03b for complete walkthrough

Comment: Perfect solution! Will add there a comment from article that helped me to implement this. 
If less won't compile your file, just remove the quotes : lessc ./src/styles/main.less ./src/styles/css/antd.css --js